# How to start blackberry application at certain time?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, alarm

I'm trying to create timer that starts my application after some period of time. Using method `ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().scheduleApplication(appDescriptor, time, true)` seems to be good solution. But according documentation

> application scheduler has a resolution of one minute. Times are rounded down to the nearest minute.

Is it any methods to prevent this or some other approach to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need finer time resolution than that then you should use a Timer to execute a TimeTask that launches the application using the ApplicationManager. But I would advise you to consider carefully then need for that level of resolution in a handheld device. It may be better to simply run in the background, and request foreground at the appropriate time than try to launch an application within those kind of tolerances.

Comment: Thanks, idea with Timer was useful.